# Как изменить background нескольких activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

Я создаю проект для учебы и в моем приложении есть семь `activity`. Я хочу поменять `background` всех `activity` нажатием на кнопку, но не знаю как это сделать. Никакой информации об этом не нашел, что удручает.

Могу я как-то это сделать? Смог изменить `background` только той `activity`, на которой находится кнопка, но при переходе на другой экран приложения и обратно все возвращается в прежнее состояние.

Comment: на [Stack Overflow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Welcome to ruSO, as you can understand from the postscript `ru`, here they ask questions in Russian :) Please translate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать темы.

1. Определить тему для всего приложения, но не для отдельной активити.

   <application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
2. style.xml например:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white_opaque</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white_opaque</item>
</style>
```

3. метод setTheme() в активити.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - использовать `SharedPreferences`. Данные, которые хранятся в `SharedPreferences` доступны в любом `activity`. По нажатию на кнопку Вы можете записать в них переменную, которая будет обозначать нужный Вам `background`, например, цвет или название, по которому Вы будете определять установленный фон.

Для того, чтобы это сделать при нажатии на кнопку, нужно:

1. Создать константу для имени файла настроек, например, так:

   `public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";`
2. Далее нужно создать параметры, которые вы хотите сохранять в настройках. Удобнее их сделать константами:

`public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_BACKGROUND = "myBackground";`

3. Объявить переменную `SharedPreferences mSettings;` и внутри метода `onCreate()` инициализировать эту переменную:

`mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

4. При нажатии на кнопку в методе onClick() нужно прописать:

```
    Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
    editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_BACKGROUND, "тут значение, которое Вы хотите сохранить");
    editor.apply();
```

5. Во всех `Activity` в `onCreate()` получайте эти данные и изменяйте фон, как Вам нужно. Для этого:

```
if(mSettings.contains(APP_PREFERENCES_BACKGROUND)) {
    string myBg = mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_BACKGROUND, "");
}
```

Строка myBg будет содержать сохранённое значение, которое Вы можете использовать для установки нужного фона.

[Вот тут можно больше почитать про SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).